# ¿Cómo volver al principio de un array después de recorrerlo?

Tags: java, array

Buenos dias,
Estoy realizando un metodo que rellena un array de usuarios con datos, según un patrón numérico. El método en sí recibe un array de enteros con ceros y unos, que sirve para determinar que posiciones del array de usuarios quedarán vacías (0 -> vacía, 1 dato)

El tamaño del patrón es arbitrario. El caso es que, cuando el patrón es de tamaño menor que el array de usuarios, hay que volver al inicio del patrón.
El metodo que estoy realizando funciona la primera vez que tengo que volver, pero cuando tengo que volver una segunda vez al inicio del patrón, me devuelve un error que indica que no puede acceder a esa posicion del array:

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10  at autoEv4.Principal.cargarDatosUsuariosPatron(Principal.java:70)
>     at autoEv4.Principal.main(Principal.java:47)*

```
class Usuario {

//Atributos
public String nif;
public String nombre;
public String apellidos;
public String correo;
public String domicilio;
public String fechaNacimiento;
public String fechaAlta;
public String claveAcceso;
public String rol;

@Override
// Sobreescritura del metodo toString()
public String toString() {

    return  "\n" 
            + "NIF:\t\t" + this.nif 
            + "\nNombre:\t\t" + this.nombre
            + "\nApellidos:\t" + this.apellidos 
            + "\nDomicilio:\t" + this.domicilio 
            + "\nemail:\t\t" + this.correo
            + "\nFecha nacimiento" + this.fechaNacimiento 
            + "\nFecha Alta\t" + this.fechaAlta 
            + "\nClave Acceso\t" + this.claveAcceso 
            + "\nRol\t\t" + this.rol + "\n";

    }
}


public class Principal {

final static int MAX_USUARIOS = 45;

// Almacén de datos resuelto con arrays

public static Usuario[] datosUsuarios = new Usuario[MAX_USUARIOS];
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] patron = {1,0,1,0,0,1};
    cargarDatosUsuariosPatron(patron);

}

private static void cargarDatosUsuariosPatron(int[] patron) {
    int i = 0;
    int longitud = 0;
    for(Usuario u: datosUsuarios) {

        if ((patron[longitud] == 0) && (longitud != patron.length-1)){
            u = null;
            i++;
            longitud++;
            }
        else if((patron[longitud] == 0) && (longitud == patron.length-1)) {
            u = null;
            longitud = 0;
            patron[i] = patron[longitud];
            i++;
            longitud++;
        }
        else if((patron[longitud] == 1) && (longitud == patron.length-1)){
                longitud = -1;
                patron[i] = patron[longitud+1];
                u = new Usuario();
                u.nif = i + "1234567E";
                u.nombre = "Nombre" + i; 
                u.apellidos = "Apellido" + "Apellido2" + i ;
                u.domicilio = "C/Luna, 2"+ i + "25078";
                u.correo = "Nombre" + i + "@gmail.com";
                u.fechaNacimiento = "1999.11.12";
                u.fechaAlta = "2017.12.3";
                u.claveAcceso = "Pass#" + i;
                u.rol = "usuario normal";
                datosUsuarios[i] = u;
                i++;
                longitud++;
            }
        else {
                u = new Usuario();
                u.nif = i + "1234567E";
                u.nombre = "Nombre" + i; 
                u.apellidos = "Apellido" + "Apellido2" + i ;
                u.domicilio = "C/Luna, 2"+ i + "25078";
                u.correo = "Nombre" + i + "@gmail.com";
                u.fechaNacimiento = "1999.11.12";
                u.fechaAlta = "2017.12.3";
                u.claveAcceso = "Pass#" + i;
                u.rol = "usuario normal";
                datosUsuarios[i] = u;
                i++;
                longitud++;
            }
        }
    mostrarUsuarios();
    }


private static void mostrarUsuarios() {
    for (Usuario u: datosUsuarios) {
        System.out.println("\n" + u);
    }
  }
} //class
```

Este es mi codigo, con la clase Usuario y la clase Principal del programa.
Con un patron suficientemente grande, o con una cantidad de usuarios pequeña, funciona correctamente, pero en este caso especifico de 45 usuarios con un patrón de 6 valores, que es lo que me requieren, no funciona.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda o guía, muchas gracias

Comment: Este tipo de error se resuelve fácil tomando el tiempo de ejecutar el programa en modo DEBUG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es que tiene que tratar siempre de optimizar el código porque está repitiendo varias veces las mismas acciones, como el incremento i++.

Aquí le paso el código, que a mi parecer es más óptimo y le soluciona su problema (o eso creo), en todo caso será una guía para su solución:

```
        private static void cargarDatosUsuariosPatron(int[] patron) {
            int iPatron = 0;
            int iUsuario = 0;
            int longitud = patron.length-1;/*limite maximo del indice del array patron*/

            for(Usuario u: datosUsuarios) {

                u = new Usuario(); /*Siempre se va a almacenar un objeto de tipo Usuario, entonces se instancia*/

                /*Se evalua si el patrón en el indice en curso, tiene valor igual a 1.
                La primera vez va a ser cero (0) el indice, entonces no hay problema al evaluarlo porque lo va a encontrar*/

                if(patron[iPatron]==1){ 

                    /*Si tiene valor 1, se almacena los datos del usuario*/
                    u.nif = i + "1234567E";
                    u.nombre = "Nombre" + i; 
                    u.apellidos = "Apellido" + "Apellido2" + i ;
                    u.domicilio = "C/Luna, 2"+ i + "25078";
                    u.correo = "Nombre" + i + "@gmail.com";
                    u.fechaNacimiento = "1999.11.12";
                    u.fechaAlta = "2017.12.3";
                    u.claveAcceso = "Pass#" + i;
                    u.rol = "usuario normal";
                }else{
                    /*Si tiene 0 se almacena null*/
                    u = null;
                }

                /*Después al arreglo de usuarios, en el indice actual de usuario, se le agrega el usuario (Sea null o no)*/
                datosUsuarios[iUsuario] = u;

                /*Se incrementan los indices de ambos arreglos, (usuarios y patron)*/
                iUsuario++;
                iPatron++;


                /*Pero si al aumentar el indice del patrón, excede el tamaño del array de patrón, 
                Se devuelve a 0, para que se pueda volver a recorrer el patron*/

                if(iPatron>longitud){
                    iPatron=0;
                }
            }

            mostrarUsuarios();
        }
```